# Send oobCode instead of link for password reset

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to send to user email with `oobCode` instead of link when they try to reset the password. But there is no variable like `%OOB_CODE%` because of this I have to send link which forces my users to open new tab with my application but I want to users to receive the `oobCode` and then copypaste it into field in my application which already opened

I found similar questions:

- [How can I send OTP(One Time Password) from Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42627378/how-can-i-send-otpone-time-password-from-firebase)
- [Is it possible to send an OTP instead of a link via Firebase Passwordless authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62951169/is-it-possible-to-send-an-otp-instead-of-a-link-via-firebase-passwordless-authen)
- [How to send OTP via email for password reset in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63710210/how-to-send-otp-via-email-for-password-reset-in-firebase)

The similar questions are old, they asked more than 2 years ago

Is there any way to send only `oobCode` instead of link in "Password reset email"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to send only oobCode instead of link in "Password
> reset email"?

The link in the "Password reset" email contains the `oobCode` as a query string parameter.

There is actually no way to generate this code via the Firebase Authentication API or via the Admin SDKs. So, you need to extract the code from the query string.